# Outputting data to JSON file csharp (unity)

Tags: json, unity-game-engine, io

I can't figure out how to output a complex data type to JSON.

I constructed a data type which basically holds smaller data types, I have also assigned the data types to new data types so they all seem to have a reference. I have looked into outputting complex data but don't seem to be able to find a problem similar to mine. I will consider appending data but this method will be much simpler if I can output the data type successfully.

Save Data Code

```
[System.Serializable]
public class SaveData
{
    public MapData mapData;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class TileData
{
    public List<BlockData> blockData;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class BlockData
{
    public Vector3 blockPosition;
    public string blockName;
    public float blockOrientation;
    public int blockLayer;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class MapData
{
    public List<TileData> tileData;
}
```

Get Map Data Method

```
    SaveData GetMapData()
    {
        mapHeight += mapStartY;
        maplength += mapStartX;

        int tileCounter = 0;

        MapData mapData = new MapData();
        SaveData saveData = new SaveData();

        List<TileData> tileList = new List<TileData>();

        for (float r = mapStartY; r < mapHeight; r++)
        {
            for(float c = mapStartX; c < maplength; c++)
            {



                Vector2 currentPosition = new Vector2(c * (blocksize)-(blocksize/2), blocksize * r -(blocksize/2));



                GameObject[] currentTile = getObjectID.RayDetectAll(currentPosition);



                if (currentTile!= null)
                {
                    //adds a tiledata list here if the tile is occupied.

                    TileData tileData = new TileData();

                    //adds a list of blocks here.
                    List<BlockData> blocks = new List<BlockData>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < currentTile.Length; i++)
                    {

                        BlockData blockData = new BlockData();


                        GameObject currentBlock = currentTile[i];

                        blockData.blockPosition = currentBlock.transform.position;
                        blockData.blockName = currentBlock.name;
                        blockData.blockOrientation = currentBlock.transform.eulerAngles.z;
                        blockData.blockLayer = currentBlock.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingOrder;                  

                        //adds a blockdata to the blocks list
                        blocks.Add(blockData);

                        Debug.LogWarning(blockData.blockName);
                    }

                    //need to assign tile data and add a new one to the list
                    tileList.Add(tileData);

                    //assins the blocks to tile data  block data list
                    tileData.blockData = blocks;

                }
                else
                {
                    //Debug.LogWarning("warning! no objects found on tile: " + currentPosition);
                }

                tileCounter++;               
            }

        }
'''


I want the file to output all the data so that i can read the data and reassign it. Right now it outputs the data wrong.
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally I think this is something that would be commented, but I can't comment yet.

If all you want is to convert an object to Json, could you use JsonUtility.ToJson() as described [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JSONSerialization.html)?

Comment: sorry forgot to add that part but there is a method using this function. Ill look into the API also.

Answer (score 0):

just to let people know I devised a new method which counted an array of all tiles and assigned it to a data type with an array in it. It managed to load from this format.